# How do I bold the bullet point headers in markdown using python?

Tags: python, markdown

I have markdown text as below:

```
text = '<div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e5e7eb; font-size: .95rem; border-radius: 8px"><h3>Income Statement</h3>\n\n1. Total Revenue:\n\nThe total revenue for xxxx for the year ended December 31, 2022 was \\$xxxxx million.\n\n2. Revenue by Source:\n\nThe breakdown of xxxx\'s revenue by source for the year ended December 31, 2022 is as follows:\n\n* Billboard:\n\t+ Static displays: \\$xxxx.x million\n\t+ Digital displays: \\$xxxx million\n\t+ Other: \\$xxx million\n\tTotal billboard revenues: \\$xxxx million\n* Transit:\n\t+ Static displays: \\$xxxx million\n\t+ Digital displays: \\$xxxxx million\n\t+ Other: \\$xxx million\n\tTotal transit revenues: \\$xxxxxxxxx million\n* Sports marketing and other: \\$xxxxx million\n\nTotal revenues: \\$xxxxx million\n\n</div>'
```

How do I bold any bullet point headers (any text that starts with an ordered or unordered list, and ends with ":". Example:  "1. Total Revenue: ")

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, "using python"? Are you saying you want to parse the markdown text out of the HTML element and modify it?

Comment: I want to update the html text with appropriate tags '<b>' or '**' for the headers

Comment: Update the html text with the appropriate tags <b></b> as appropriate.  There should be plenty of tutorial about updating html text files.

Comment: The question is how to identify text that starts with an ordered or unordered list, and ends with ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *quick-and-dirty* way is to use regular expressions to change the text, e.g.:

```py
import re

text = '<div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e5e7eb; font-size: .95rem; border-radius: 8px"><h3>Income Statement</h3>\n\n1. Total Revenue:\n\nThe total revenue for xxxx for the year ended December 31, 2022 was \\$xxxxx million.\n\n2. Revenue by Source:\n\nThe breakdown of xxxx\'s revenue by source for the year ended December 31, 2022 is as follows:\n\n* Billboard:\n\t+ Static displays: \\$xxxx.x million\n\t+ Digital displays: \\$xxxx million\n\t+ Other: \\$xxx million\n\tTotal billboard revenues: \\$xxxx million\n* Transit:\n\t+ Static displays: \\$xxxx million\n\t+ Digital displays: \\$xxxxx million\n\t+ Other: \\$xxx million\n\tTotal transit revenues: \\$xxxxxxxxx million\n* Sports marketing and other: \\$xxxxx million\n\nTotal revenues: \\$xxxxx million\n\n</div>'

text = re.sub(r"(^\s*[*+]\s*)([^:]+):", r"\g<1>**\g<2>:**", text, flags=re.M)
text = re.sub(r"(^\s*\d+\.\s*)([^:]+):", r"\g<1>**\g<2>:**", text, flags=re.M)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
<div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e5e7eb; font-size: .95rem; border-radius: 8px"><h3>Income Statement</h3>

1. **Total Revenue:**

The total revenue for xxxx for the year ended December 31, 2022 was \$xxxxx million.

2. **Revenue by Source:**

The breakdown of xxxx's revenue by source for the year ended December 31, 2022 is as follows:

* **Billboard:**
        + **Static displays:** \$xxxx.x million
        + **Digital displays:** \$xxxx million
        + **Other:** \$xxx million
        Total billboard revenues: \$xxxx million
* **Transit:**
        + **Static displays:** \$xxxx million
        + **Digital displays:** \$xxxxx million
        + **Other:** \$xxx million
        Total transit revenues: \$xxxxxxxxx million
* **Sports marketing and other:** \$xxxxx million

Total revenues: \$xxxxx million

</div>
```